# How does Cipher Block Chaining relate to AES?

Tags: encryption, aes, fips, cipher-selection

I was reading FIPS197 for a class (found here: http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf ) trying to find some sort of specific relation between CBC and AES. I guess my problem is that I don't really know what to look for. I take it that CBC is a component of AES?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CBC is just one of the modes of operation that can be applied to a general block cipher, i.e. it is not tied specifically to AES. For die diverse modes of operation for block encryption see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation

Comment: Should add that ECB mode shouldn't be used.

Comment: CBC or CTR mode should also be not used alone as they do not provide any cipher-text integrity and there can be active attacks on these modes.